# Iphone 7 wont turn on

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 7 and for the past 2 weeks it's been turning on and off. I did a hard reset 3 times and it was good for a little bit. Now last week it shut off and I tried doing a hard reset and it wont turn on. What do I do??

Comment: Is iOS up to date? Have you tried restoring the phone?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with your phone's battery. Check out Apple's [iPhone Battery and Performance](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208387) page and scroll down to the "Preventing unexpected shutdowns" section. They have a very detailed explanation of various factors that contribute to unexpected shutdowns.

If your phone is unexpectedly turning off even whilst connected to an AC power supply, then there might be an issue with your phone's hardware and you should contact some technical support for further help and inquiries.

If there's absolutely nothing wrong with your phone's battery or other hardware, then it might be some app or other piece of software that's causing the issue, and you should most probably do a complete factory reset of your phone. It's definitely not an iOS software bug, that much I can tell you.